# In jQuery Select element that has redundant or has two of same class

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

Say in this example:

```
<div class='a a'></div>
<div class='a a'></div>
<div class='a'></div>
<div class='a a'></div>
<div class='a a'></div>
<div class='a'></div>
<div class='a a'></div>
```

In jQuery, how do I select the `div` elements with two `a` classes?

I am using the [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) library, just so you know I don't control the rendered tags, and there are elements in the rendered calendar that has two of a same class, I want to select those.

Comment: at first place why are you using same class twice and why not two different classes?

Comment: It is not me who is using two same classes, its the library I'm using.

Comment: The same question ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034736/select-element-that-has-two-of-same-class-name-or-has-redundant-class-in-jquery

Comment: will it be always `class="a a"` or it can be like `class="a b a"` OR `class="a a b"`?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar yeah the classes change and are not fixed to `a a` only.

Comment: ok, I have provided answer to both the possibilities but for my second anwser you should go with regex as provide by technophyle and Phong

Comment: Can you explain where and which part of this plugin used duplicate classes?!

Comment: @Pedram the `td` elements with `off` classes.

Comment: I see, but it has something like this `off ends active start-date available in-range` don't see any duplicate classes

Comment: it no make scense *!* not to me, not for who made this plugin, why author should use duplicate classes? I just see many `td` with `off` class, it used once per `td`, not `off off`

Comment: Question: Why does this matter?  it either has the class or doesn't as far as css and selectors go.  If it's there twice, it still has it.  If you do `$(".a").removeClass("a")` it removes both anyway, which is how you would find/remove it as you've tagged this [jquery].

Comment: @Pedram tick the `maxSpan` option and you'll find the elements with `off off`. See screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/VozNrOA.

Comment: @freedomn-m It matters on the project I am working on. Some of the guys have answered below, with best patience, and I salute them for that.

Comment: @RicardoGreen okay, I saw that, It's funny, why author did something! anyway, now you want to select which one? `off ends` or `off disabled` or what?

Comment: I'm not saying you don't *think* it's a problem, otherwise you wouldn't have asked, and not adding an answer that duplicates an existing one doesn't put down that answer.  I'm asking in what scenario this would be needed as there seems a more plausible work around / just seems unnecessary (or an XY problem).  You're not required to give me an answer, it's just a query.

Comment: @Pedram this issue has been solved by the answers of Phong and Bhushan Kawadkar below. Thanks for your helpful inputs though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should count the occurrences of classes to get exactly the item as you wish like below.

```js
$(".a").filter(function(){
  var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/);
  var countClassA = classes.filter(c => c === "a").length;
  return countClassA > 1;
}).addClass('selected');
```

```css
div{
   padding: 5px;
}

.selected{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a a'>Double AA</div>
<div class='a a'>Double AA</div>
<div class='a'>Single A</div>
<div class='a a'>Double AA</div>
<div class='a a'>Double AA</div>
<div class='a'>Single A</div>
<div class='a b a'>Double AA</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, but this would not solve my issue. My actual scenario is lots of `td` elements, sorry for not clarifying that. Updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look @Ricardo Green

Comment: Sir Phong can you please update so it returns and adds a class like `b` to the selected elements? Just that and I'll be selecting this as the answer.

Comment: Updated, Please take a look at @Ricardo Green

Comment: Brilliant, sir. I confirm this works in the project I am working on and it fixes the issue. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

if class value always be like `class="a a"`then you can make use of attribute selector as shown in below code with `div[class="a a"]`

```js
$(function(){
   $('div[class="a a"]').addClass('b');
})
```

```css
.a {
  color: green;
}
.b {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a a'>Double A</div>
<div class='a a'>Double A</div>
<div class='a'>Single A</div>
<div class='a a'>Double A</div>
<div class='a a'>Double A</div>
<div class='a'>Single A</div>
<div class='a a'>Double A</div>
```

for another case where `class` may have third class at the start / end / middle then in that case we need to manually calculate the classes

```js
$(function(){
  $('div.a').filter(function(){
     var classVal = $(this).attr('class');
     var classes = classVal.split(" ");
     var count = 0;
     for(var i=0; i<classes.length; i++) {
        if(classes[i] == "a") {
          count++;
        }
     }
     return count==2;
  }).addClass('b');
});
```

```css
.a {color:  green;}
.b {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a a'>Double A</div>
<div class='a a'>Double A</div>
<div class='a'>Single A</div>
<div class='a a'>Double A</div>
<div class='a a'>Double A</div>
<div class='a'>Single A</div>
<div class='a a'>Double A</div>
```

Comment: It's not correct if the class format different from `a a`. Please check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60035079/9071943

Comment: thats why i asked OP if this is the case or not ... if class will always be `a a` then what i have posted is the best approach but if there will be another class in between or at the end or start then we need to count the occurrences of classes.

Comment: Yep, I do think so, sir.

Comment: To me this answer is one of the closest, especially that it does select and return the elements I want. If only the second answer was answered earlier than @Phong's. Thanks to your answers and patience Bhushan Kawadkar. Going with Phongs as it was the first closest answer. This deserve a vote up though.

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class attribute and see if it contains multiple `a` classes:

```js
$(".a").on("click", function() {
  const classes = $(this).attr('class');
  const count = classes.split(/\ba\b/).length - 1;
  if (count === 2) {
    console.log('A A !!!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a a'>A A</div>
<div class='a a'>A A</div>
<div class='a b'>A</div>
<div class='a b a'>A A</div>
<div class='b a a'>A A</div>
<div class='a'>A</div>
<div class='a a'>A A</div>
```

Comment: It's not only the same my idea along with code, but also slightly adjust incorrectly :) `split` return an array of items. So your answer is incorrect.

Comment: why downvote it? mind explaining what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is this solve your problem? it's only select the `div` with double a class name:

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('class') == 'a a') {
    $(this).addClass('active')
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a a b'>a a b</div>
<div class='a a'>a a</div>
<div class='a'>a</div>
<div class='a a c'>a a c</div>
<div class='a a d'>a a d</div>
<div class='a'>a</div>
<div class='a a e'>a a e</div>
```